# Fetching data from Facebook page's events page

Tags: ios, swift, api, facebook-graph-api

I would like to pull data from a Facebook event page that would fetch all the events listed by a Facebook page. I have to up the iOS SDK, but i am now unsure how to call the Graph API. I found the PAGE ID for a Facebook group page i want to take the events from by looking at the page's source code and finding "PAGEID".

I have set it up all in my dashboard along with my Bundle ID. The only left is to call the Graph API, but i am unsure and left confused when trying to following their [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift).

Comment: Are you using the `Swift SDK` or the Objective C one?  You tagged your question here with `swift`, but you linked to the docs of Facebook's Objective C SDK

Comment: @WilliamGP I am using Swift SDK

Answer (score -1):

Show us the code you tried already and what is not working. 
Have you tried this already? (where `{page-id}` is your page's ID):

```
let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/{page-id}/events")) { httpResponse, result in
  switch result {
  case .success(let response):
    print("Graph Request Succeeded: \(response)")
  case .failed(let error):
    print("Graph Request Failed: \(error)")
  }
}
connection.start()
```